# change design of subscribe page

Tags: php, phplist

I installed phpList into my local and created subscribe page.

By default it looks like this.
[image]

This is default design of all the subscriber pages in phpList. But what if i want to change the designs for this page.

Let's say i want to design something like this [site](http://www.exchangedeluxe.com).

If you can guide me to tutorial or documentation(how to customize design of subscriber page of phpList), that would be great.

**Update**
This is my code in which when i press enter after entering data in text field, it will take me to subscriber page.

```
<html>
<body >
    <form action="http://objectlounge.hosted.phplist.com/lists/?p=subscribe&id=1" method="post" name="subscribeform">

        <div id="inputfield">
            <input class="emailField" type="text" name="email" id="emailAdd"/>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a few notions on HTML/CSS, you can take a look [here](http://docs.phplist.com/CustomSubscribeForm.html) this is from the documentation and it looks like quite simple

Comment: thanks for this document. I am bit confused about this. I made changes in post action methods. but what happens is when i click submit in page it redirects me to the page which i have created from phpList and automatically fills email address.

Comment: But what i want is, it should not display phpList page but just insert record in subscriber list of phpList.

Comment: where should i add this line <input type="hidden" name="subscribe" value="yes">

Comment: Somewhere into the form, but without source code I can't help you more

Comment: added code. Please give your suggestion in reference to this code.